# Error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, angular7

Whenever I start my angular app I have this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at default~app-app-module~9ca28b07.js:4519
    at Module../node_modules/cdk-table-exporter/fesm5/cdk-table-exporter.js (default~app-app-module~9ca28b07.js:4521)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../node_modules/mat-table-exporter/fesm5/mat-table-exporter.js (default~app-app-module~9ca28b07.js:5013)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/app-material.module.ts (default~app-app-module~9ca28b07.js:36901)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (it.js:47)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at main-wqrng.js?v=92fb42:43
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

I've tried cdk-table-exporter and mat-table-exporter with npm but still is giving me this error.
This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "webqreteang",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build p": "ng build --prod",
    "mock": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy/proxy.conf.json --open --host 0.0.0.0 --watch --configuration mock",
    "mock real be": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy/proxy.be.conf.json --port 4201 --open --host 0.0.0.0 --watch --configuration mock",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.7",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.7.1",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.2.15",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@standard-coop/coop-stj-menu": "^7.0.0-beta.1",
    "@standard-coop/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-richtexteditor": "^17.3.28",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^5.0.2",
    "cdk-table-exporter": "^1.2.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "devextreme": "^18.2.4",
    "devextreme-angular": "^18.2.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^1.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "devextreme-cli": "1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: pls show us your .ts

Comment: Seems like a compatibility issue. Are you sure you have all the dependencies for both libraries?

Comment: Try uninstalling `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material` (both versions `7.3.7`) and try installing version `7.2.15` of each. With `npm install @angular/material@7.2.15` and `npm install @angular/material@7.2.15`.

Comment: @MattU when I try to install them it gives the error `No matching version found for @angular/material@7.2.15`

Comment: I wonder if you can keep 7.3.7 of @angular/material?

Comment: I've reinstalled 7.3.7. But the error still show up... I have all the dependencies set correctly

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of mat-table-exporter (1.2.2) has a problem that affects only the users with Angular version 7 and below.
You can use 1.2.1 for now, there will be a release addressing this issue.[(issue 21)](https://github.com/HalitTalha/mat-table-extensions/issues/21)

Edit:
Now you can use the latest version 1.2.5